# How to fetch specific values from multi dimential array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I display an array using `print_r` statement

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Price
            [value] => 18,000
            [type] => textfield
            [group] => 1
            [published] => 1
            [ordering] => 1
            [alias] => Price
        )
        [1] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Brand
            [value] => Nokia
            [type] => select
            [group] => 1
            [published] => 1
            [ordering] => 2
            [alias] => Brand
        )
        [2] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Mobile Model
            [value] => X-plus
            [type] => textfield
            [group] => 1
            [published] => 1
            [ordering] => 3
            [alias] => MobileModel
        )
        [3] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Contact Name
            [value] => XYZ
            [type] => textfield
            [group] => 1
            [published] => 1
            [ordering] => 4
            [alias] => ContactName
        )
        [4] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Email
            [value] => XYZ@gmail.com
            [type] => textfield
            [group] => 1
            [published] => 1
            [ordering] => 5
            [alias] => Email
        )
        [5] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => Contact Number
            [value] => 03328914989
            [type] => textfield
            [group] => 1
            [published] => 1
            [ordering] => 6
            [alias] => ContactNumber
            )
        [6] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 7
            [name] => Province
            [value] => KPK
            [type] => select
            [group] => 1
            [published] => 1
            [ordering] => 7
            [alias] => Province
        )
        [7] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 8
            [name] => City
            [value] => Peshawar
            [type] => textfield
            [group] => 1
            [published] => 1
            [ordering] => 8
            [alias] => City
        )
    )
)
```

I want to get only the value of Brand. What is the appropriate approach to achieve it?

Comment: Arrays can be accessed with `$var[0]` and object properties with `->name`. Chain them `$var[1][2]->three->four[5]->six[7][8][9]->ten` as needed.

Comment: which index has your brand?

Answer (score 1):

Add some spaces to your output to really understand the structure first.

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Array (
   [0] => stdClass Object (
       [id] => 1 [name] => Price [value] => 18,000 [type] => textfield [group] => 1 [published] => 1 [ordering] => 1 [alias] => Price 
   )
   [1] => stdClass Object (
       [id] => 2 [name] => Brand [value] => Nokia [type] => select [group] => 1 [published] => 1 [ordering] => 2 [alias] => Brand 
   )
   [2] => stdClass Object ( 
      [id] => 3 [name] => Mobile Model [value] => X-plus [type] => textfield [group] => 1 [published] => 1 [ordering] => 3 [alias] => MobileModel
   )
```

Let's call the main array `$arr`. First thing we notice is that it's inside another array for some reason, so everything is in `$arr[0]`. If you know that *Brand* will remain at index [2], you can simply use the following:

```
$brand = $arr[0][2]->value; // Assigns "Nokia" to $brand
```

Otherwise, we can always loop through that array you have (`$arr`) and find whose name is *Brand*. Something like this:

```
$brand = '';
foreach ($arr[0] as $obj) {
    if ($obj->name == 'Brand') {
        $brand = $obj->value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the index of the table you want to get :

```
  echo print_r($table[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
foreach($your_array[0] as $arr)
{
     echo $arr->name;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having an array combined with an object.
You can access "Brand" this way for a variable $a which contains this construct:

```
$brand = FALSE;
foreach ($a as $a1) {
    if (is_array($a1)) {
        foreach ($a1 as $a2) {
            if (is_object($a2) && $a2->name == 'Brand') {
                $brand = $a2;
                break;
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

The variable $brand will contain the resulting object which has the name "Brand" or FALSE if no "Brand" has been found. You could enhance this to also compare with "alias".

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your array into a variable

```
$records = array(
array(
    'id' => 2135,
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
),
array(
    'id' => 3245,
    'first_name' => 'Sally',
    'last_name' => 'Smith',
),
array(
    'id' => 5342,
    'first_name' => 'Jane',
    'last_name' => 'Jones',
),
array(
    'id' => 5623,
    'first_name' => 'Peter',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
)
```

This way you can then call on a specific attribute, in your case

```
$brand = array_column($records, 'Brand');
print_r($brand);
```